# Selenium Wait Until HTML Element Changes

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape bookings data from a website. Upon entering the site, I must:

1. Change the default date range (at first, the site displays bookings data for the default date range) to a date range I want to search for
2. Click the 'Refresh' button
3. Wait a bit for the website to update the displayed results on the page.

Using Selenium, Python, and BeautifulSoup, when I execute Selenium commands to update the fields for the date range, and click the 'Refresh' button, by the time the code reaches the line where I extract HTML data using BeautifulSoup, **the default bookings data for the default website date range is extracted, and not the bookings data for the date range I filled in.**

Upon observation, it appears the site is moving by too quickly with Selenium to extract the updated data which takes some time to load. I tried to solve this using `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` but this returns highly inconsistent results.

I wanted to detect an HTML element that allows for stable extraction with no errors. I realized that when I click the 'Refresh' button, this particular element ...

```
<div id="textArea" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
```

... changes to ...

```
<div id="textArea" style="visibility: hidden; display: block;">
```

... and changes back to ...

```
<div id="textArea" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
```

... when the bookings data on the page is updated.

Is there a Selenium command that can detect this change prior to moving onto the next lines in my Python code? For instance, after clicking the 'Refresh' button, a "wait until style=visibility is visible" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    a = driver.find_element_by_id('textArea').get_attribute('style')
    if a == r"visibility: hidden; display: block;"
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(.05)
while True:
    a = driver.find_element_by_id('textArea').get_attribute('style')
    if a == r"visibility: visible; display: block;"
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(.05)
```

This will wait until it goes invisible, then to visible before your program does anything

Comment: Case 1: What if element changes from visible to hidden and then hidden to visible in given time period (I believe 5 seconds wait here)? Better we can reduce it to as less as possible and try. Case 2: What if an attribute added with some extra content than listed above? We can make it dynamic just to check hidden vs visible..

Comment: For the first concern, you can probably create a timer for the first loop that breaks out of it after n seconds. For the second concern, you should just use an element of the html instead of ID that is more unique